# Browser returns SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Tags: browser, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, self-signed-certificate

i've created my own CA and intermediate CA with openssl.
On my Zyxel AP i've created an csr.
I signed the csr through my intermediate CA and imported the server
cert to my zyxel AP.
I've also uploaded the fullchain root CA (CA and Intermediate) to my zyxel AP.
I'm using ubuntu so i've installed fullchain CA in my cerstore (/usr/local/share/ca-certificates  | update update-ca-certificates)
I also imported the fullchain CA in my Browser Cert Store (tested with firefox, brave)....

But when i now call up the webgui from my AP i get the follwing message:

SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

This happens for all browsers.

When i check with curl or openssl, everything looks good:

```
curl -vvI https://zyxel.home.arpa
 ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
.
.
.
SSL certificate verify ok.


openssl s_client -CAfile ca-chain-bundle.cert.pem https://zyxel.home.arpa
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

What can i try to fix this browser issue?

Edit 1:

without CAfile:

```
openssl s_client -connect zyxel.home.arpa:443
.
.
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
.  
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
.
```

Edit 2:

@ President James K. Polk, here are the output of the server crt:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:                37:5b:25:e6:31:1b:7e:f7:63:14:30:e1:b6:ca:d2:11:a2:83:44:1c
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = DE, ST = Home, O = Home Inc., CN = Home Intermediate-CA, emailAddress = admin@home.sh
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 22 20:20:47 2022 GMT
            Not After : Nov 22 20:20:47 2023 GMT
        Subject: CN = zyxel.home.arpa, C = DE, ST = Home, L = Home, O = Home Inc, OU = IT
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:aa:be:cf:97:ad:fd:da:1a:9b:c4:af:9a:07:ac:
                    b7:08:bb:e3:eb:b8:d0:dc:fc:34:bf:8c:c8:5b:3f:
                    37:a7:20:7d:7e:eb:c9:e1:ce:c6:a8:84:2a:a3:35:
                    74:83:c9:62:94:ad:92:5b:c5:54:99:9e:14:c9:2b:
                    73:44:75:06:de:d4:dc:13:a6:0c:8c:b6:d9:84:e2:
                    1e:51:f8:2f:83:3c:62:95:ca:32:39:07:2b:81:41:
                    f9:88:08:95:fb:f9:c2:10:f0:de:25:b6:e2:83:f0:
                    f2:86:41:7d:5d:09:91:3b:04:b8:5f:74:b7:f5:2e:
                    e8:fa:9b:f5:17:a7:ef:d1:45:ed:05:8e:f3:8e:c3:
                    a1:96:42:9d:dd:ef:2f:03:81:97:b9:c5:df:9c:41:
                    3b:b6:9d:7b:09:a0:bf:ad:e8:6a:e2:05:ef:2b:fc:
                    67:4d:5a:dd:a4:ba:7b:58:a8:65:53:08:06:60:00:
                    08:85:12:34:31:9b:93:27:d2:35:75:00:f0:01:f5:
                    58:7f:1a:e5:1f:e5:08:8a:14:ca:c4:17:4d:90:ec:
                    30:7a:38:3e:ad:90:db:08:46:35:c4:6e:a7:8e:81:
                    77:eb:15:47:50:7e:d1:71:d5:09:38:64:c3:fa:08:
                    2a:31:a0:bd:87:0b:70:27:b3:42:fe:20:de:b1:be:
                    87:a9
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL Server
            Netscape Comment: 
                OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                F5:D6:9B:95:CA:2C:8E:41:92:5F:3E:3E:9C:D5:31:CE:6A:D0:F8:95
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:25:0C:ED:3A:E1:A0:B9:86:A0:FB:43:9F:20:F0:F4:C0:5E:85:C4:D7
                DirName:/C=DE/ST=Home/L=Home/O=Home Inc./CN=Home Root-CA/emailAddress=admin@home.sh
                serial:01
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
```

and here's the output ofthe generated csr on the zyxel AP:

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: CN = zyxel.home.arpa, C = DE, ST = Home, L = Home, O = Home Inc, OU = IT
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:aa:be:cf:97:ad:fd:da:1a:9b:c4:af:9a:07:ac:
                    b7:08:bb:e3:eb:b8:d0:dc:fc:34:bf:8c:c8:5b:3f:
                    37:a7:20:7d:7e:eb:c9:e1:ce:c6:a8:84:2a:a3:35:
                    74:83:c9:62:94:ad:92:5b:c5:54:99:9e:14:c9:2b:
                    73:44:75:06:de:d4:dc:13:a6:0c:8c:b6:d9:84:e2:
                    1e:51:f8:2f:83:3c:62:95:ca:32:39:07:2b:81:41:
                    f9:88:08:95:fb:f9:c2:10:f0:de:25:b6:e2:83:f0:
                    f2:86:41:7d:5d:09:91:3b:04:b8:5f:74:b7:f5:2e:
                    e8:fa:9b:f5:17:a7:ef:d1:45:ed:05:8e:f3:8e:c3:
                    a1:96:42:9d:dd:ef:2f:03:81:97:b9:c5:df:9c:41:
                    3b:b6:9d:7b:09:a0:bf:ad:e8:6a:e2:05:ef:2b:fc:
                    67:4d:5a:dd:a4:ba:7b:58:a8:65:53:08:06:60:00:
                    08:85:12:34:31:9b:93:27:d2:35:75:00:f0:01:f5:
                    58:7f:1a:e5:1f:e5:08:8a:14:ca:c4:17:4d:90:ec:
                    30:7a:38:3e:ad:90:db:08:46:35:c4:6e:a7:8e:81:
                    77:eb:15:47:50:7e:d1:71:d5:09:38:64:c3:fa:08:
                    2a:31:a0:bd:87:0b:70:27:b3:42:fe:20:de:b1:be:
                    87:a9
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
            Netscape Comment         :OpenSSL Generated Certificate
            Requested Extensions:
                X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                    F5:D6:9B:95:CA:2C:8E:41:92:5F:3E:3E:9C:D5:31:CE:6A:D0:F8:95
                X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment, Certificate Sign
                X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                    TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
                X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                    othername: UPN::zyxel.home.arpa, DNS:zyxel.home.arpa
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        1b:04:05:e6:02:89:4d:1d:67:a4:bb:15:06:20:93:58:c3:2b:
        72:3c:e0:39:cd:f0:ea:6e:3a:db:33:02:3e:fa:ca:67:ec:e4:
        58:a5:cf:ad:c0:51:b1:bb:0d:22:3f:a5:fc:ac:d1:e9:90:d6:
        71:71:5d:dc:56:f1:14:21:cb:a3:53:be:0a:32:43:8f:8a:74:
        55:08:e3:1d:44:7d:72:f3:94:7f:1a:99:71:b7:97:be:a6:ff:
        a8:cf:95:f5:3b:c3:c6:6c:e3:ef:d9:39:8d:03:17:2e:15:2c:
        92:ee:00:88:5f:23:21:a4:ac:27:c6:66:00:a5:5d:89:8d:f3:
        87:43:34:35:16:e4:bd:72:38:ba:2c:27:f4:c9:08:22:aa:86:
        21:6c:98:9f:4b:2b:7e:5e:6a:aa:5c:19:80:29:32:6d:4f:78:
        1d:db:5b:1d:a1:bc:31:86:e9:65:af:ee:30:35:12:ce:d4:18:
        b1:06:57:e3:da:f6:63:b0:48:53:64:0a:4b:ca:2a:20:d6:5d:
        90:1a:bf:af:bb:d3:18:e8:5e:42:2f:3f:c8:96:20:63:66:9e:
        2e:b1:2a:fa:82:f6:ba:d0:d3:7f:e7:a5:5d:f5:3a:fb:a9:b0:
        54:a5:0a:14:48:8a:37:1e:e8:32:6c:73:7d:4c:af:dc:21:bc:
        24:60:9e:2c
```

Solution:

i forgot to add the Subject Alt Name part into my openssl.cnf (thanks for the hint President James K. Polk):

```
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1 = IP
DNS.1 = DNS NAME
```

Comment: I've just tried chromium browser, it returns another message:

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: What is the value of the common name in the server certificate, and what are the values of all the names in the subject alternative names extension of the server certificate?

Comment: @President James K. Polk
Just added the server certificate output into "edit2 Section" of the main post and also the generated csr from my zyxel ap

Comment: You don't have the hostname in the subject alternative name (SAN) extension of the certificate. I don't know if all (or any) browsers require it but it is required by the relevant standards.

Comment: Thank's so much!
I've added the Subject alt. part in my openssl.cnf file and no it works!